# How to dynamic partitioning in Hive using tez engine?

Tags: hive, sqoop

I sqooped data from mysql to hdfs.

```bash
sqoop import --username aaa --password bbb --num-mappers 1 --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:1234;database=test_db" --query "select DATE, DATA01, DATA02, DATA03 FROM test_tbl where \$CONDITIONS"  --delete-target-dir --target-dir /data/test/raw_data/sqoop_tbl/ --as-textfile
```

And create table in hive located above data's path.

```bash
create external table sqoop_tbl (DATE TIMESTAMP, DATA01 FLOAT, DATA02 FLOAT, DATA03 FLOAT) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' stored as textfile location '/data/test/raw_data/sqoop_tbl';
```

And i retrieve above table in hive result:

```bash
2022-12-13 10:22:12     86.0    70.0    85.0
2022-12-13 10:22:20     86.0    70.0    85.0
2022-12-13 10:22:28     86.0    70.0    85.0
2022-12-13 10:22:38     86.0    70.0    85.0
2022-12-13 10:22:46     86.0    70.0    85.0
```

then i create partition table like this:

```bash
create table if not exists partitioned_data (DATA01 FLOAT, DATA02 FLOAT, DATA03 FLOAT) PARTITIONED BY(date STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

and insert data from test_tbl to partitioned_data like this:

```bash
insert into table partitioned_date partition (date) select substring(DATE,0,10), DATA01, DATA02, DATA03 from test_tbl;
```

this work well but, it's partition is not date.

```bash
expected partition key,val:
date=2022-01-02
date=2022-01-03
date=2022-01-04
date=2022-01-05
date=2022-01-06
date=2022-01-07
date=2022-01-08
date=2022-01-09
...

result partition key,val:
date=0.0
date=0.1
date=0.2
date=0.3
date=0.4
date=0.5
date=0.6
date=0.7
date=0.8
date=0.9
date=1.0
date=1.1
date=1.2
...
```

Why partition's val is wrong??

Answer (score 0):

Ok... This is my mistake. when I querying "insert ~ select ~", select's column order is problem. I re-order partition key to last position, and it work!!!